# Can I remove the word "algorithm" from the header and keep only the caption,also I "want for loop" to be indented after step 3

Tags: captions, indentation, algorithms

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}
\caption{Math  algorithm}
\STATE \textbf {Step 1} $\rightarrow $ gather the data 
\STATE \textbf {Step 2} $\rightarrow $ estimate  matrix 
\STATE \textbf {Step 3} {$\rightarrow $\\ {

      \FOR {$k=0$ to final} 
                       \STATE \hspace*{1.45cm} $\Rightarrow$  calculate 
                       \STATE \hspace*{1.45cm} $\Rightarrow$  calculate error 
                        \STATE \hspace*{1.45cm} $\Rightarrow$ update  
                        \ENDFOR}}
                         \STATE \textbf {Step 10} $\rightarrow $ calculate            
\end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Check the other "algorithm" packages, another one might be a better fit to your problem (I'm partial to `algorithm2e`). Captions for various floats can be customized with e.g. the `float` package

Comment: Do you want to remove just "Algorithm" or also the number?

Answer (score 4):

1. To remove only the name "Algorithm" from the caption you can use the caption package and declare a format for the label using \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat (see example below); if you want to suppress the name *and* the numbering, you can use

   ```
   \captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty}
   ```
2. To facilitate indentation I defined two commands `\bindent` (begin indentation) and `\eindent` (end indentation) which give you user specified indentation. The default is `2em`, but you can control this through an optional argument (see example below; in particular, notice that now there's no need for thos manual `\hspace` commands you were using).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{noname}{#2}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=noname}

\newlength\myindent
\setlength\myindent{2em}
\newcommand\bindent[1][\myindent]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\itemindent}{#1}
  \addtolength{\algorithmicindent}{#1}
}
\newcommand\eindent{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}
\caption{Math  algorithm}
\STATE \textbf{Step 1} $\rightarrow $ gather the data 
\STATE \textbf{Step 2} $\rightarrow $ estimate  matrix 
\STATE \textbf{Step 3} {$\rightarrow $ {
\bindent
  \FOR {$k=0$ to final}
    \bindent[1.45cm] 
    \STATE $\Rightarrow$ calculate 
    \STATE $\Rightarrow$ calculate error 
    \STATE $\Rightarrow$ update
    \eindent  
    \ENDFOR\eindent}
  }
\STATE \textbf{Step 10} $\rightarrow $ calculate            
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As a side note, I'd like to suggest you switching to the [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package which offers you more flexibility and customization possibilities; it has a compatibility option for `algorithmic` (refer to the package documentation).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the term "Algorithm 1", you could insert two commands inside the algorithm environment. The first one `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}` removes the numbering, while the second one `\floatname{algorithm}{}` removes the word 'Algorithm'.

```
\begin{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\floatname{algorithm}{}

\caption{My Algorithm}
%% the algorithm 

\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Doesn't this leave something anyway?