# How can I remove/change the "Algorithm X" label from the caption of an algorithmicx algorithm?

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithmicx, algpseudocode

I am using `algpseudocode` for writing an algorithm, and I would like to remove the "Algorithm X" from the title when adding a caption. How can I do this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx, algpseudocode, algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \textbf{Input:} Placeholder input \\
    \textbf{Output:} Placeholder output
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{foo}{x} \\
        \Return $x+1$
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{Placeholder caption}
    \label{placeholder}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:[image: Output]

How can I remove "Algorithm 1" from the title, and replace it with my own text, say "My text 1", where the counter also increases? I would still like to have a caption at the top, I just want to replace "Algorithm 1" with something else. I tried using `figure` instead of `algorithm`, but I would like to have the other formatting (horizontal lines) that the `algorithm` environment provides.

I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/259256/117052), but that refers to `algorithmic`, not `algorithmicx`. Additionally, I would prefer a solution that can be applied to a specific algorithm instead of the whole document, since I have other algorithms where I want to keep the title intact.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remove caption label *and* entry in `\listofalgorithms`

If you want to remove the caption label entirely, you could use the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and then `\caption*` (note, though, that this will remove the algorithm from the `\listofalgorithms`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{algorithmicx, algpseudocode, algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\textbf{Input:} Placeholder input \\
\textbf{Output:} Placeholder output
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{foo}{x} \\
    \Return $x+1$
    \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption*{Placeholder caption} % <-- CHANGED LINE
\label{placeholder}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

### Remove caption label (`\listofalgorithms` unchanged)

Using the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package again, we can use `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}` (see [p. 6 of the `caption` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx, algpseudocode, algorithm}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} % <-- CHANGED LINE
\textbf{Input:} Placeholder input \\
\textbf{Output:} Placeholder output
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{foo}{x} \\
    \Return $x+1$
    \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Placeholder caption}
\label{placeholder}
\end{algorithm}

\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

### Change caption label locally (`\listofalgorithms` unchanged)

If you want to locally change the caption label, you can use the `\floatname` command (see [§4.4 of the `algorithms` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf#subsection.4.4)). For this you don't even need the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx, algpseudocode, algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{Something} % <-- CHANGED LINE
\textbf{Input:} Placeholder input \\
\textbf{Output:} Placeholder output
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{foo}{x} \\
    \Return $x+1$
    \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Placeholder caption}
\label{placeholder}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you (+1), this is partly helpful. Is there a way to replace the "Algorithm" title with something else, however? I will accept this if I don't get a better solution.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Working on it, the question got edited a few seconds before I posted my answer

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Appreciate your help in editing the question as well.